# A controller with this name is not registered (not able to call that controller)

Tags: angularjs

I have just started working with AngularJs and i am stuck at this place:

i have index.html and inside that am including script tags like angular oclazyload and my application.js file

```
<html ng-app="mymodule">
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-css-injector.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="application.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
            <h1>Sample Page</h1>
            <div ng-include="login"></div>
    </div>


</body>
```

inside my application.js i am using oclazyload cssInjector and nginclude to load another js,css and html file(login.js,style.css and login.html).

My application.js file

```
var mymodule=angular.module("mymodule",["oc.lazyLoad","angular.css.injector"]);
mymodule.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$ocLazyLoad,cssInjector){

            $ocLazyLoad.load("/task1/login.js");
            cssInjector.add("style.css");
            $scope.login="login.html";
         });
```

In my login.js file i am defining one controller as logincontroller

login.js file:

```
var mymodule=angular.module("mymodule",[]);
 mymodule.controller("logincontroller",function($scope)
  {
  $scope.title="hello World!!!";
  })
```

and in my login.html i am calling that controller i.e(logincontroller)

```
<div ng-controller="logincontroller">
        {{title}}
    </div>
```

all the files are loading but i am getting error that controller with this name is not registered.

Comment: Offtopic, If you just started with angularjs recommend swapping directly to angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have timing problem. Can be `login.html` loading before `login.js` ? Try to change `$scope.login` in `$ocLazyLoad.load("/task1/login.js")`promises. Like

```
$ocLazyLoad.load("/task1/login.js").then(function(){ $scope.login = 'login.html '});
```

And you must change this

```
var mymodule=angular.module("mymodule",[]);
 mymodule.controller("logincontroller",function($scope)
 {
    $scope.title="hello World!!!";
 })
```

to this

```
var mymodule=angular.module("mymodule");
 mymodule.controller("logincontroller",function($scope)
 {
    $scope.title="hello World!!!";
 })
```

Comment: It worked.. thanx alot i was banging my head on this for past few hours i knew that i had to do something with (.then function) but was not able to figure it out..thanx alot buddy